# How to get items of an entity's collection property using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Suppose we have Hotels that have rooms, and each room has a room number, how can I display all of the room numbers starting from `context.Hotels` using Linq instead of foreach ?

Illustration:

```
var Rooms = context.Hotels.Select(e => e.Rooms);

foreach (var room in Rooms)
{
    var list = room.Select(r => r.Number);
    foreach(number in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```

Obviously I can directly display the numbers from the room entity but this isn't my actual code just to illustrate what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply selecting the room number, using `SelectMany`, as in:

```
var roomNumbers = context.Hotels.SelectMany(h => h.Rooms.Select(r => r.Number));
```

Or in case they need to be distinct numbers:

```
var roomNumbers = context.Hotels.SelectMany(h => h.Rooms.Select(r => r.Number)).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I needed! I have been seeing that method popping in IntelliSense and been ignoring it lol